# Duplicate Primary Key Entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create 2 tables for poll and poll answers using the following SQL. I am getting the error "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY". Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `phppoll` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `phppoll`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `polls` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` text NOT NULL,
    `desc` text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `polls` (`id`, `title`, `desc`) VALUES (1, 'What''s your favorite way to browse?', '');

INSERT INTO `polls` (`id`, `title`, `desc`) VALUES (2, 'What''s your favorite way to use tech?', '');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `poll_answers` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `poll_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `title` text NOT NULL,
    `votes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `poll_answers` (`id`, `poll_id`, `title`, `votes`) VALUES (1, 1, 'Laptop', 0), (2, 1, 'Desktop', 0), (3, 1, 'Tablet', 0), (4, 1, 'Other', 0);

INSERT INTO `poll_answers` (`id`, `poll_id`, `title`, `votes`) VALUES (2, 1, 'Laptop', 0), (2, 2, 'Desktop', 0), (2, 3, 'Tablet', 0), (2, 4, 'Other', 0);
```

Comment: Your code appears to work:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4af2ed5d89b77bdfc007924f6cd93d19.

Comment: Do not insert ID values by yourself, when you are auto incrementing. Just zero them out or start with minimum auto increment value.

Comment: Because the DUP key is in `(2, 1, 'Desktop', 0),` is == `(2, 1, 'Laptop', 0),`

Comment: Work Around: `INSERT INTO `poll_answers` (`id`, `poll_id`, `title`, `votes`) VALUES (5, 1, 'Laptop', 0), (6, 2, 'Desktop', 0), (7, 3, 'Tablet', 0), (8, 4, 'Other', 0);`

Comment: Thanks guys! Used @RiggsFolly solution and seems to work, appreciate all the comments/ answers though

Answer (score -1):

As I point out in my comment, your code is fine.

Your problem is probably due to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`.

You are probably running the code multiple times, and the table is not replaced the second time.  What you want instead is `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`.

Answer (score -1):

i think if you try `INSERT IGNORE` it may help you, go here for more details:

(https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/)